# Open Firefox Browser Console with a button click

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-console

I want to write a Firefox WebExtension that would consist of a button, which would open the **Browser Console** upon click. How can I achieve that? Is there a URL for the Browser Console which can be used with **windows.create()** or 
**Window.open()**?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Maybe it is. I have found the Web Console URL: chrome://devtools/content/webconsole/webconsole.xul

Comment: Most chrome:// URLs cannot be opened using WebExtensions tabs.create or windows.create.

Comment: I have found this: **let HUDService = require("devtools/client/webconsole/hudservice"); HUDService.openBrowserConsoleOrFocus();** Have not tested it yet, but it probably should work from a XUL extension. Is it possible to write such a button directly into the browser's code? Like **browser/content/browser.xul** ?